# Get image from object and display on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, object

I want to get an image from an object in JavaScript and display it via HTML.

The text parts are working fine, like the movie name etc., but I cannot see my image. The only thing I see is black_adam.jpg as text.
The image is in the same folder as my index.html. I tried to add a slash in front of `imgFile: "/black_adam.jpg"`.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- FAVICON -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="#" />
    <!-- FONTS -->

    <!-- ICON LIBRARY -->

    <!-- PROJECT STYLES -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->

    <style>
      .movie {
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif">
    <div class="movie">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <h2 class="movie-title">/h2>
      <p class="release"></p>
      <p class="duur"></p>
      <p class="cast"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
      const movieEl = document.querySelector(".movie");

      const movie = {
        id: 1,
        name: "Black Adam",
        description:
          "Nearly 5,000 years after he was bestowed with the almighty powers of the Egyptian gods-and imprisoned just as quickly-Black Adam (Johnson) is freed from his earthly tomb, ready to unleash his unique form of justice on the modern world.",
        releaseYear: 2022,
        runtime: "2 hr 4 min",
        rating: 6.9,
        cast: ["Dwayne Johnson", " Aldis, Hodge", " Pierce Brosnan"],
        imgFile: "black_adam.jpg"
      };
      
      movieEl.innerHTML =
      `
      <div class="img">${movie.imgFile}
        <h2 class="movie-title">${movie.name}</h2>
        <p class="release">${movie.releaseYear}</p>
        <p class="duur">${movie.runtime}</p>
        <p class="cast">${movie.cast} </p>
      </div>
      `
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does it not work this way?

Comment: Have you tried `<div class="img"><img src="${movie.imgFile}">`?  And what does your css class 'img' look like?

Comment: _"explain why is does not work this way"_ - because you did absolutely nothing, that would tell the browser that this was _not_ meant to be plain text. If you really don't know how embedding images in HTML works, then you should go look that up.

Comment: In your code, you arent't actually outputting the value of your image as an `<img />` tag. Instead of `<div class="img">${movie.imgFile}` try `<div class="img"><img src="${movie.imgFile}" />` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing your file name as text is that you've done nothing to display the image as an image in your HTML

The line `<div class="img">${movie.imgFile}`, aside from not having a close tag for your `</div>`, should be written as follows

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="${movie.imgFile}" />
</div>
```

or in a single line if you prefer

```
<div class="img"><img src="${movie.imgFile}" /></div>
```

Comment: Hello, Cliff Burton thanks it worked. I now see what i did wrong